# Installing mariadb-connector-c on Rasbian

Tags: installation, mariadb, raspbian

I'm trying to install the libaries for mariadb-connector-c on my Raspberry Pi 3.
But I didn't done that before and are not able to do that.
I installed mariadb-server on my Pi with apt-get.
Now I try to install all libaries from [Connector C](https://downloads.mariadb.org/connector-c/). Especially a stable version. So i tried to install Version 2.3.3.

I downloaded the source files (mariadb-connector-c-2.3.3-src.tar.gz). 
Than I tried to run cmake on my pi (cannot find a "simple" description of how to use it) and got an error:

```
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Looking for sys/types.h
*** stack smashing detected ***: cmake terminated
Aborted
```

I cannot find that package with apt-get and so on. 
Can anyone help me please?
The C(++)-Code which will run on the pi is no problem but I do not understand how to install those packages.

On my Pi is Raspbian (Jessie) installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

The sd card is defect and cannot write sectors without errors. Even a *fsck* seems to repair the defects but the next (heavy) write operation produces the same errors.

--> Replaced the sd-card and everything works fine.